# Get the relational algebra generated by Apache Calcite

Tags: sql, apache-calcite

I'm trying to build a translator from SQL to some format that I can parse and execute using my code. Is it possible to parse a query through Apache Calcite and get the output in some parseable format, like JSON?

Answer (score 0):

When you parse the query, you can just traverse the objects representing the relational algebra which are generated. If you really want to convert to JSON, you can use [RelJsonWriter](https://calcite.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/calcite/rel/externalize/RelJsonWriter.html).